# Form update in jquery and cakephp 3.X

Tags: jquery, mysql, cakephp

I have updated a form in jquery and cakephp 3.

and there is a database error coming ,where the form post data are saved in to the database

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'to = 'jhj@hjgh.jhj' , bcc = 'fdg@ryre.yy' WHERE id = 1' at line 1

```
 public function ajaxEditquicklinksForm() {
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout('ajax');


    $frmWigData = $this->FormWidgets->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->data) {

        $data = $this->request->data;
        $frmWigData->id = $data['id'];
        $frmWigData->frm_name = $data['frm_name'];
        $frmWigData->to = $data['to'];
        $frmWigData->bcc = $data['bcc'];            
        if ($this->FormWidgets->save($frmWigData)) { //showing error here
            echo json_encode("Updated");
        }
    }exit;
}
```

I have tried to `print_r($frmWigData);`

And it returns

```
(
[id] => 2
[frm_name] => Business with ushjhjh
[to] => fdf@ty.hjhj
[bcc] => hjh@ulj.kjk    
)
```

Comment: error comes from your query. Pls update your post and add your query string.

Comment: @long what is the error in that query?

Comment: this query: to = *...'jhj@hjgh.jhj' , bcc = 'fdg@ryre.yy' WHERE id = 1*

Comment: There is also showing error near there but which one?

Comment: there is an syntax error in your query. So could you please show me your complite *insert* query?

Comment: In cakephp 3 this is the insert query `$this->FormWidgets->save($frmWigData)`

Comment: why don't you user `patchEntity` instead of manual assigning every single property of the entity?